# API in a LocalHost works in Postman and doesn't work in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, axios, postman

[image][image]

**Situation** The API is located at http://localhost:44000/
In Postman it is working and returning the value, but when I make this request in React Native through Axios, it returns a Network error,  . does anyone know how to solve?

**Attempted Resolutions**

- I tried to use the command: adb reverse tcp:44000 tcp:44000 and it
  didn't work again, I also tried using Control + M > Settings >
  debug server and host. and I put 10.0.2.2:44000 and it didn't solve
- I hope that passing the information in the body, it returns an object
  with the api information by the POST method
- replaced 'localhost' with variations of 10.0.2.2 and 127*

**In summary,** I'm going to upload this request to some server and apparently it will work, it seems to be an SSL error from C# itself

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: thanks for listening! i managed to solve the problem by passing the command adb reverseport tcp and passing the ports that are being used in the api